# How do remove between two patterns in bash

Tags: html, regex, bash

How do i remove the text between two patterns in a line of a file, i have list of lines here i show only two lines for simpliciy

```
 <sup id="Gen.2.23" class="v0_2_23">23</sup>Anke Adam pulo:</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_23">“La ke non nerrepi-heihei pen arrepi-lo lapen ne-ok pen a-ok-lo;</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_23">bangpi aphan ‘Arloso’ pusi hangpo,</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_23">pima bangpi ke Pinso pensi enlo.”</span></p>
 <sup id="Gen.2.24" class="v0_2_24">24</sup>Anke Adam pulo:</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_24">“La ke non nerrepi-heihei pen arrepi-lo lapen ne-ok pen a-ok-lo;</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_24">bangpi aphan ‘Arloso’ pusi hangpo,</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_24">pima bangpi ke Pinso pensi enlo.”</span></p>
```

i want to remove the text between `</span></p><p class="q2">` to `">`

The result which i need in output is shown below

```
 <sup id="Gen.2.23" class="v0_2_23">23</sup>Anke Adam pulo: “La ke non nerrepi-heihei pen arrepi-lo lapen ne-ok pen a-ok-lo;bangpi aphan ‘Arloso’ pusi hangpo, pima bangpi ke Pinso pensi enlo.”</span></p>
 <sup id="Gen.2.24" class="v0_2_24">24</sup>Anke Adam pulo: “La ke non nerrepi-heihei pen arrepi-lo lapen ne-ok pen a-ok-lo;bangpi aphan ‘Arloso’ pusi hangpo, pima bangpi ke Pinso pensi enlo.”</span></p>
```

When i used  `sed 's/<\/span><\/p><p class="q2">*.*">//g'` it removes the first `<span` and last `">`

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser?

Comment: @jeremysprofile - Not a duplicate of a non-sense question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a non-greedy match, otherwise the `.*>"` will match as much possible on the line.  The syntax for non-greedy matching is generally `*?`, although I don' believe it is supported by sed.  So, for your case you could do something like,

```
perl -pe 's;</span></p><p class="q2">.*?">;;g' input.html
```

But, as @melpomene suggests, regexps aren't a good choice for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this yields what you want:

```
sed 's/<\/span><\/p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_23">//g' file
```

To avoid escaping you can use a different separator like:

```
 sed 's|</span></p><p class="q2"><span class="v0_2_23">||g' file
```